# C++ How should I store the data in containers

Tags: containers

I'm working on a game with wave system of spawning monsters.
Config file is like:

; Type 1
(wave (type 1) (stage 1) (creature 10 1)  ; First stage
(wave (type 1) (stage 1) (creature 15 1)
(wave (type 1) (stage 2) (creature 17 5)) ; Second stage
(wave (type 1) (stage 2) (creature 24 1))

; Type 2
(wave (type 2) (stage 1) (creature 24 1)) etc.

I'm totally lost in containers and got no clue how it should be done.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question would be improved by a code example showing what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

First, figure out what those things are.  Does every config file have exactly two types, or do you need a List of types that can be any number of Types?  That kind of detail.

Second, create objects that represent those things.  Usually classes.

Third, create a mechanism of parsing the input from the config file.  Overloading the >> operator is the obvious way, especially for a school project.  In the function that does that, you can read the input and enter it into the data type you created.

Comment: Types will indicate the 'level' number. Let's say there will be like 10 different types which just tell that this monster list bounded with specific type.

so it's just list of things that will be spawned
about config files, I got no problems with that, my main problem is I don't know exactly how to build proper data structure for it.

I though about making it that way.
std::map<int, SLevel> Instance;

struct SLevel
{
   int Stage;
   int CreatureId;
   int CreatureNum;
};

Comment: I'm not sure about it since I would have to iterate it few times to find all creatures on desired stage.